# Nested if statements - R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am having a problem with multiple if statements. The output is always taken from the first condition, even if the condition is not correct.. Can anybody point out what am I doing wrong?

code:

```
for(i in 1:length(data_model3$Gewicht)){
    if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 1){
      data_model3$LIXshipping <- 3.26 
    }
    else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 1 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 2){
      data_model3$LIXshipping <- 3.26 
    }
    else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 2 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 3){
      data_model3$LIXshipping <- 3.86 
    }
    else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 3 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 4){
      data_model3$LIXshipping <- 3.86 
    }
    else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 4 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 5){
      data_model3$LIXshipping <- 3.86 
    }
    else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 5 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 10){
      data_model3$LIXshipping <- 4.39 
    }
    else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 10 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 20){
      data_model3$LIXshipping <- 4.81 
    }
    else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 20 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 31.5){
      data_model3$LIXshipping <- 6.34 
    }
    else 
      data_model3$LIXshipping <- 17.09 
}
```

output:

```
count_code  Gewicht LIXshipping
281         4.67    3.26
683         3.34    3.26
903         14.56   3.26
7390        14.62   3.26
2778        2.86    3.26
2778        10.37   3.26
```

It might be a completely basic question for some of you, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Use `cut` instead of nested `if/else`.  Also, you can use the vectorized `ifelse`

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235377/changing-continuous-ranges-to-categorical-in-r

Comment: `data_model3$LIXshipping <- ...` is changing the whole column.

Comment: Please put the result of `dput(data_model3)` in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by one line (+ one line for the data):

```
data_model3 <- data.frame(Gewicht=1:40)
data_model3$LIXshipping <- as.numeric(as.character(cut(data_model3$Gewicht, breaks=c(0,2,5,10,20,31.5, 100), labels=c(3.26, 3.86, 4.39, 4.81, 6.34, 17.09), right=FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd put the rules in a table...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

rules = data.table(
  Gewicht = c(1:5, 10, 20, 31.5, Inf), 
  v = c(3.26, 3.26, 3.86, 3.86, 3.86, 4.39, 4.81, 6.34, 17.09)
)


   Gewicht     v
1:     1.0  3.26
2:     2.0  3.26
3:     3.0  3.86
4:     4.0  3.86
5:     5.0  3.86
6:    10.0  4.39
7:    20.0  4.81
8:    31.5  6.34
9:     Inf 17.09
```

And then use a "rolling join" to apply them

```
DF[, v := rules[DF, on="Gewicht", roll=-Inf, v] ]


    Gewicht     v
 1:       0  3.26
 2:       2  3.26
 3:       4  3.86
 4:       6  4.39
 5:       8  4.39
 6:      10  4.39
 7:      12  4.81
 8:      14  4.81
 9:      16  4.81
10:      18  4.81
11:      20  4.81
12:      22  6.34
13:      24  6.34
14:      26  6.34
15:      28  6.34
16:      30  6.34
17:      32 17.09
18:      34 17.09
19:      36 17.09
20:      38 17.09
21:      40 17.09
    Gewicht     v
```

Data:

```
DF = data.frame(Gewicht = seq(0,40,by=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly answering the question, but I wanted to present what the code with vectorized `ifelse` would look like, as suggested by @akrun and @Tim, plus a few optimizations of mine:

```
data_model3 <- data.frame(Gewicht=1:40)

data_model3$LIXshipping <- 
    ifelse (data_model3$Gewicht < 2,  3.26,
    ifelse (data_model3$Gewicht < 5,  3.86,
    ifelse (data_model3$Gewicht < 10, 4.39,
    ifelse (data_model3$Gewicht < 20, 4.81,
    ifelse (data_model3$Gewicht < 31.5, 6.34, 17.09)
))))
```

The result is the following:

```
> data_model3
   Gewicht LIXshipping
1        1        3.26
2        2        3.86
3        3        3.86
4        4        3.86
5        5        4.39
6        6        4.39
7        7        4.39
8        8        4.39
9        9        4.39
10      10        4.81
11      11        4.81
12      12        4.81
13      13        4.81
14      14        4.81
15      15        4.81
16      16        4.81
17      17        4.81
18      18        4.81
19      19        4.81
20      20        6.34
21      21        6.34
22      22        6.34
23      23        6.34
24      24        6.34
25      25        6.34
26      26        6.34
27      27        6.34
28      28        6.34
29      29        6.34
30      30        6.34
31      31        6.34
32      32       17.09
33      33       17.09
34      34       17.09
35      35       17.09
36      36       17.09
37      37       17.09
38      38       17.09
39      39       17.09
40      40       17.09
```

I've removed the redundant conditionals (when the values assigned to the variable was the same as the previous one). You don't need the double guards like `data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 1 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 2` because the first condition was already tested in the prior `if` statement.

Note that your original code doesn't do anything when the input is exactly 1, 2, 3 and so on because you only used the strict comparison operators `<` and `>`, but usually we put at least one of `<=` and `>=` to guard all cases. I assumed this was a mistake and optimized them away.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(data_model3)
data_model3[, LIXshipping:= ifelse(Gewicht < 2 & Gewicht != 1, 3.26,
                                   ifelse(Gewicht > 2 & Gewicht < 5 & !(Gewicht %in% c(3, 4)), 3.86,
                                          ifelse(Gewicht > 5 & Gewicht < 10, 4.39,
                                                 ifelse(Gewicht > 10 & Gewicht < 20, 4.81,
                                                        ifelse(Gewicht > 20 & Gewicht < 31.5, 6.34, 17.09)))))]
```

I have shortened some categories based on the values that you assign to them (for example you assign the same shipping value for categories 1 and 2)
As to what you are doing wrong in your code, you should assign the value to `data_model3$LIXshipping[i]`,  so `data_model3$LIXshipping[i] <- 4.81`.

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to index **data_model3$LIXshipping[i]** in my code. Thank you @jogo for pointing it out.

```
for(i in 1:length(data_model3$Gewicht)){
        if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 1){
          data_model3$LIXshipping[i] <- 3.26 
        }
        else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 1 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 2){
          data_model3$LIXshipping[i] <- 3.26 
        }
        else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 2 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 3){
          data_model3$LIXshipping[i] <- 3.86 
        }
        else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 3 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 4){
          data_model3$LIXshipping[i] <- 3.86 
        }
        else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 4 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 5){
          data_model3$LIXshipping[i] <- 3.86 
        }
        else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 5 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 10){
          data_model3$LIXshipping[i] <- 4.39 
        }
        else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 10 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 20){
          data_model3$LIXshipping[i] <- 4.81 
        }
        else if (data_model3$Gewicht[i] > 20 & data_model3$Gewicht[i] < 31.5){
          data_model3$LIXshipping[i] <- 6.34 
        }
        else 
          data_model3$LIXshipping[i] <- 17.09 
}
```

Comment: But this may not be the best way of solving it.  You could at least use a vectorized if else.

Comment: @jogo - Boy, I love those one-liners! Nice code-golfing!